# How do I change the color of the author text in the Title (first) frame?

Tags: beamer, color, titles

```
\documentclass[T]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Example Presentation}
\author{Author 1\\Author 2}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

{\usebackgroundtemplate
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{caestitlepage}}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What changes would I need to make in order to make the "author text" white??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code.

Comment: Is `\author{\textcolor{white}{Author 1}\\Author 2}` enough ?

Comment: No that only changes it for only one author.

Comment: I mean you can do it for both of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to use the proper color template (`author` in this case); for example:

```
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white}
```

A complete example (with a dummy background):

```
\documentclass[T]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for font size substitution
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz} %for dummy background

\title{Example Presentation}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white}
\author{Author 1\\ Author 2}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\tikz\fill[blue,opacity=0.4](0,0)rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);]}

%{\usebackgroundtemplate
%{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{caestitlepage}}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Actually, also percusse's suggestion is fine; indeed:

```
\documentclass[T]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for font size substitution
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz} %for dummy background

\title{Example Presentation}
\author{\textcolor{white}{Author 1}\\ \textcolor{white}{Author 2}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{\tikz\fill[blue,opacity=0.4](0,0)rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);]}

%{\usebackgroundtemplate
%{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{caestitlepage}}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

provides the same picture reported above.

Comment: @user25318: you're welcome :)